# How to change an interface implementation based on a preprocessor directive without compiling the other implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

So basically, I have a program that relies on server sided code. There is a specific algorithm that I want to protect, so I run it server sided so that people can't simply decompile my software and steal it. The downside is that for testing it can be a bit slow, for each operation a request is made to the test server.

What I want to achieve is to have 2 implementations of my interface ICrypto. I want an OfflineCrypto and an OnlineCrypto implementation, and to switch these based on conditional compilation. What I want is to not compile the OnlineCrypto class at all if I build for Release.

Right now I have a #if DEBUG directive around my whole OfflineCrypto class, and a #if RELEASE directive around my whole OnlineCrypto class, and in my CryptoFactory I have a #if directive as well for instantiating the class.

I hate to have to switch configuration every time I want to edit one of the implementations, as without switching configuration all the code is greyed out and IntelliSense does not work. But as far as I know, I have to have the #if directive surrounding the whole class to ensure that this class is not compiled for the Release build.

So, my question is if there is a more elegant solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Do not switch the code, only the assignment.

```
public static ICrypto CryptographyProvider;

#IF DEBUG
  CryptographyProvider = new ICryptoDebugImplementation();
#ELSE
  CryptographyProvider = new ICryptoReleaseImplementation();
#ENDIF
```

Comment: I already have this, like I stated in my post. The thing is, I want to prevent the Debug implementation from being compiled completely. Right now I do this by having a preprocessor directive (#if DEBUG) around the whole class implementation, but I find this ugly, and intellisense does not work if I am not on the Debug configuration.

Comment: @nevsnirG It would be near impossible to avoid Compilation too. Indeed your propblem is that *because* you do noit compile it, Intellisesne will not concern itself with it. Like it does not concerns itself with Comments. You want/need it to compile. My best idea would be to make the Accessor Keyword swap between public and private depending on Debug state.